# Searching for grandfather’s birth certificate (1903, Hungary)

Tags: birth-records, 1900s-decade, hungary

My grandfather’s name is Pal Kutassy, he was born on February 18 1903, apparently in a town called lisson in Hungary.

However, I can’t find such a town in Hungary. He left on a ship headed from Austria to Australia on 31 August 1949, called the Skaugum, he left with his wife Margit Kutassy who was from Ogyalla Hungary, and a 7 month old son.

How can I get his birth certificate?

Comment: I'm redacting the name of your father because he was born less than 100 years ago and you've provided no evidence of his decease - see our Privacy Policy in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH! Where does the information about your grandfather's town name come from? Do you have a scan of a document with the town name that you can [edit] into your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the source for your information, in the Arolsen Archives (https://collections.arolsen-archives.org/en/document/81764777); it indeed has a typewritten "Lisson" for his birthplace, which doesn't exist. The closest the gazetteers get is a Slovak Lutheran village in Hont county called Lissó, but that fits neither his name nor his religion.

The Hungarian genealogy society has a marriage indexed in Lepsény (which is either Fejér or Veszprém county, depending on when you're talking about) that may be relevant, but unfortunately the image is not available online. (It's a multi-part film with some images that are too recent.)

```
Groom: Kutassi Pál
Father: Kutassi Pál
Mother: Bakonyi Eszter
Bride: Simonka Margit
Father: Simonka Péter
Mother: Bányai Eszter
Date: 17 Feb 1936
Entry number: 4
Place: Lepsény (Fejér)
Film: 5016210
Image: 183
```

Theoretically, a 1934 marriage record should or at least could identify the birthplaces of the bride and groom, so I suggest you try the Lookup Service of the Family History Library in Salt Lake City (https://www.familysearch.org/en/library/record-lookup-service). You'll be at the mercy of the assigned volunteer's understanding or interpretation of the rules and restrictions, but it's free.

Whether that marriage turns out to be "yours" or not, you may not be able to get a birth record for your grandfather: if the birthplace is now in Slovakia (like Ógyalla, which is now Hurbanovo, Slovakia), then the civil registrations are not online, and the church registers that are available on FamilySearch only sometimes include 20th century births.

(Note that in no case will what you find be anything that can be called a "birth certificate". It'll be a birth or baptismal registry entry, or possibly an extract of same.)